# TcpClient read on server loses initial bytes

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm trying to send a sort of a *Ping-Pong* communication through `TcpClient` `Networkstream`.

I have a client which send continous data to server that has to notify the client for data obtained in order to allow client to send some information again.

My flow (in a loop) is something like this:

// loop

- Client send data to server (next data length)
- Server notifies client that it received and correctly read that data.
- Client send the full data to server
- Server notifies client that it received all data and correctly interpretated it.

Now, it all works fine, but once I send whole data to my server, it is reading them skipping the initial bytes and for this it fill final bytes of received message with many 0.

Note: I need to keep connection open, so I can't close-open it every time.

This is my code, I removed some lines in order to make it more readable:

**Client side code (relevant)**

```
using(var clientStream = client.GetStream()){

    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    while (client.Connected)
    {
        SerializableSharedObject sso = new SerializableSharedObject(connectionIdTest)
        {
            timeStamp = DateTime.Now,
            customerCode = "TEST",
            desktopCode = "DESK",
            objectType = (int)SerializableObjectType.SCREEN,
            screen = GrabDesktop() //a bitmap
        };
        byte[] ba = ObjectToByteArray(sso);
        byte[] userDataLen = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)ba.Length);

        //sending to server the next data length
        clientStream.Write(userDataLen, 0, 4);

        //waiting from server the confirmation that he received data length
        bool lengthSent = false;
        while (!lengthSent)
        {
            if (clientStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                byte[] sendResult = new byte[1];
                if (clientStream.Read(sendResult, 0, 1) > 0)
                {
                    if (sendResult[0] == (byte)1)
                        lengthSent = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //sending to server the whole data
        clientStream.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

        //waiting from server the confirmation of receiving whole data
        bool contentSent = false;
        while (!contentSent)
        {
            if (clientStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                byte[] sendResult = new byte[1];
                if (clientStream.Read(sendResult, 0, 1) > 0)
                {
                    if (sendResult[0] == (byte)1)
                        contentSent = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Server side code (relevant)**

```
using( var clientStream stream = client.GetStream()) 
{
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            byte[] readMsgLen = new byte[4];
            while (!clientStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                // wait for data... 
            }

            // read the next data length
            clientStream.Read(readMsgLen, 0, 4);
            int dataLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(readMsgLen, 0);

            byte[] readMsgData = new byte[dataLen];

            //send to client the confirm message.
            clientStream.Write(new byte[1] { (byte)1 }, 0, 1);

            while (!clientStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                // wait for data... 
            }

            // read the whole data
            clientStream.Read(readMsgData, 0, dataLen); // <-- incomplete

    }
}
```

I noticed that the final read from server is skipping data. With an example of 244000 (+/-) bytes send, it skipped the first 20 and filled last 20 `bytes` with `0` values.

I tried debugging many times and noticed that it looks like the `stream` is reading only the bytes from the "now moment", losing the firsts bytes send based on delay of receiving the data. Debugging it skipped around 200 `bytes`, with a breakpoint and waiting a couple of seconds it skipped many thousands.

How can I make the stream read every bytes starting from `0 position`?

I already tried implementing `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`, but the result was the same.

thanks

---

Github repo [here](https://github.com/Shinitorix/ScreenShare_TcpClientDemo)

Comment: You are receiving a Keep-Alive which is a message with zero bytes.  The client sends message automatically every 5 seconds so server doesn't close connection.  TCP send datagrams with max size of ~1500 bytes.  During routing a datagram can be split and recombined.  Windows uses timers so it is possible in same machine for messages to get split.  So you have to read until end of message before processing a message.  Either use an end character (like a return for ascii data) or add a byte count to beginning of message so you know when you reached the end.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `Read` will return the number of bytes you asked for. That's why it returns the number of bytes that it's provided. You need to pay attention to that number, it could be as small as 1, in theory. If you're expecting a certain number of bytes, it's up to you to loop until you've received them all (or move to a higher level primitive that already gives you what you seem to want - *messaging*, rather than TCP's continuous stream of bytes.

Comment: Aside: you don't need to do this manual acknowledgement process that you do here. You can send the length immediately followed by the data. TCP/IP guarantees delivery so you'll get an error if the message could not be delivered to the recipient.

Comment: @jdweng but I don't understand why it skips some initial bytes and not middle or end bytes. For example, if I send something like [1,0,0,2,3,4,5], I receive this: [3,4,5,0,0,0,0] as if the stream was shifted backward

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried looping for bytes, but it didn't work either.. I tried adding a "for" loop with length as total count, but it read only the first byte and waited the next write call..

Comment: @500-InternalServerError If I remove the "callback", I still get the same error at the second iteration. If TCP guarantees the delivery, how should I read all datas if both iteration and bulk write/read result in errors? I'm surely doing something wrong (first time working with TCP connection) but I don't really know what.

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistakes. Can you break this down into a repro that you can post?

Comment: Its not "as if the stream was shifted backward". It's "as if the earlier bytes were delivered during an earlier call to `Read` but I didn't pay attention to the extra bytes in that buffer"

Comment: When a Communication device is constantly sending you often have to flush data until you get a start of message.  In your case  from code posted this doesn't appear to be the case.  It is probably best that you use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see what is happening and determine if the issue is in client or server.  It looks like you a just missing the first 4 bytes which is the length of the message.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I added the full repo on github.. I think it's easier. I added also a README about how to use it. Above I edited my question adding the link. thanks for your support

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's a good point. I had some deeper searches but looks like nothing else listening and nothing more is sent. I tried listening more bytes than I send, but the read method return exactly mine.. Tbh I have no idea why my clients aren't talking correctly. I tried also removing all callbacks and using only two writes and two reads with fixed lengths, still no success

Comment: @jdweng the 4 bytes were an example I wrote by hand, the real stream has 200k+ bytes and skips 20, 200 or more bytes. I'm actually working on localhost with both server and client to debug, will a sniffer work anyway? I still think that this behaviour is awkard.

Comment: Yes. As long as it is on same machine.

Comment: @jdweng I installed Wireshark, and looks like my client send the correct number of bytes, so the problem must be on my server. but how should I fix it in order to read all bytes?

Comment: You do not need the while loop [while (!clientStream.DataAvailable)} to wait for data.  The Read method will wait.  Once you get dataLen then you have to keep calling the Read until entire message is received.

Comment: @jdweng wow! removing all "dataAvailable" made it half working! thanks!! Now it works like charm for some seconds (nearly 30), but after those it throws an exception "binary stream 0 does not contain a valid binaryheader". I gotta solve that but for the rest it looks working thanks! If you have any idea about that error, any further advice would be appreciated!